# Problema con ASCII al importar una API a un .json para guardarlo posteriormente

Tags: python, json

Tengo un problema, necesito crear un .json para almacenar los datos que me proporciona una API (diccionarios), así que uso este código y bueno, me funciona bien

```
def API(self):
        url = "https://api.json" """example"""
        resp = requests.get(url)
        api = json.loads(resp.content)
        with open('api.json', "w") as C:
            json.dump(api, C)
```

Después uso otras funciones y separo lo que necesito, ahora ocurre que en la cadena hay caracteres especiales como acentos, signos de exclamación, eñe, y me lo pone codificado, esta información que consigo la tengo que guardar posteriormente en una base de datos después de procesarla, pero necesito que no tenga esos "códigos" y no sé si sea mejor guardarla en otro .json o en un .txt

Cualquier ayuda sería buena

Ejemplo de datos:

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "title": "Saman Fest", 
            "type": 1, 
            "bands": 4, 
            "cartel": ["Los Cocineros", "Ramayana", "CacetVersus", "La vida Hippie"], 
            "layout": {
                "general": [4, 10], 
                "vip": [1, 10]
            }, 
            "prices": [50, 100], 
            "date": "2022-04-01"
        },
        {
            "title": "KenaAna & Guako", 
            "type": 1, 
            "bands": 2, 
            "cartel": ["Guako", "kenaAna"], 
            "layout": {
                "general": [4, 10], 
                "vip": [1, 6]
            }, 
            "prices": [30, 50], 
            "date": "2022-04-01"
        },
        {
            "title": "El famtasma del paraninfo", 
            "synopsis": "En esencia, la trama de El Fantasma del Paraninfo es una historia que combina romance, m\u00fasica, terror, misterio y tragedia. Trata de Eric, un hombre misterioso, un genio musical, que se enamora perdidamente de Cristina, una joven y talentosa artista, a quien inspira musicalmente", 
            "type": 2, 
            "cartel": ["Leonardo DeCapo", "Cendella", "Ed Ramiro"], 
            "layout": {
                "general": [5, 10], 
                "vip": [4, 3]
            }, 
            "prices": [5, 10], 
            "date": "2022-05-10"
        },
        {
            "title": "Romeo & Julieta", 
            "synopsis": "En Verona, dos j\u00f3venes enamorados, de dos familias enemigas, son v\u00edctimas de una situaci\u00f3n de odio y violencia que ni desean ni pueden remediar. En una de esas tardes de verano en que el calor \u00abinflama la sangre\u00bb, Romeo, reci\u00e9n casado en secreto con su amada Julieta, mata al primo de \u00e9sta", 
            "type": 2, 
            "cartel": ["Romeo Gonzalez", "Julieta Hernandez"], 
            "layout": {
                "general": [1, 5], 
                "vip": [1, 5]
            }, 
            "prices": [10, 25], 
            "date": "2022-12-31"
        }
    ]
}
```

Es un diccionario con lista de diccionarios, al importar la API me codifica algunos datos en ASCII en vez de UTF-8 ejemplo:
sale la palabra **recién** así ---> `reci\u00e9n`

Comment: Utiliza el método `translate`

Comment: Cuando debo usarlo? al guardar mis nuevos datos o al conseguir la API?

Comment: Un ejemplo de los datos sería realmente útil para saber de que estamos hablando.

Comment: @CandidMoe ya hice la actualización con ejemplos

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas "normalizar" el string primero:

**unicodedata.normalize(form, unistr)**

Retorna la forma normalizada form para la cadena Unicode unistr. Los valores válidos para form son “NFC”, “NFKC”, “NFD” y “NFKD”.

El estándar Unicode define varias formas de normalización de una cadena Unicode, basándose en la definición de equivalencia canónica y equivalencia de compatibilidad. En Unicode, varios caracteres se pueden expresar de diversas formas. Por ejemplo, el carácter U+00C7 (LETRA C LATINA MAYÚSCULA CON CEDILLA) también se puede expresar con la secuencia U+0043 (LETRA C LATINA MAYÚSCULA) U+0327 (CEDILLA COMBINABLE).

Para cada carácter, hay dos formas normalizadas: la forma normal C y la forma normal D. La forma normal D (NFD) también se conoce como descomposición canónica y traduce cada carácter a su forma descompuesta. La forma normal C (NFC) primero aplica una descomposición canónica y luego vuelve a componer los caracteres combinados previamente.

Además de las dos anteriores, hay dos formas normalizadas adicionales basadas en la equivalencia de compatibilidad. En Unicode, se admiten ciertos caracteres que normalmente se unificarán con otros caracteres. Por ejemplo, U+2160 (NUMERAL ROMANO UNO) es realmente lo mismo que U+0049 (LETRA LATINA MAYÚSCULA I). Sin embargo, esta característica está soportada por Unicode para ser compatible con los conjuntos de caracteres existentes (por ejemplo, gb2312).

La forma normalizada KD (NFKD) aplicará la descomposición de compatibilidad, es decir, reemplazará todos los caracteres de compatibilidad con sus equivalentes. La forma normalizada KC (NFKC) primero aplica la descomposición de compatibilidad, seguida de la composición canónica.

Incluso si dos cadenas Unicode están normalizadas y parecen iguales para un lector humano, si una tiene caracteres combinados y la otra no, es posible que no se comparen como iguales.

#### Demo

```
import unicodedata

texto = "En Verona, dos j\u00f3venes enamorados, de dos familias enemigas, son v\u00edctimas de una situaci\u00f3n de odio y violencia que ni desean ni pueden remediar. En una de esas tardes de verano en que el calor \u00abinflama la sangre\u00bb, Romeo, reci\u00e9n casado en secreto con su amada Julieta, mata al primo de \u00e9sta"

output = unicodedata.normalize('NFD', texto).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
print(output)
```

La variable `output` no es un string, sino un arreglo de bytes. Cada caracter ocupa una posición.

produce:

```
b'En Verona, dos jovenes enamorados, de dos familias enemigas, son victimas de una situacion de odio y violencia que ni desean ni pueden remediar. En una de esas tardes de verano en que el calor inflama la sangre, Romeo, recien casado en secreto con su amada Julieta, mata al primo de esta'

Process finished with exit code 0
```